# How to reverse the byte shifts after I have extracted a value in C?

Tags: c, hash, byte, endianness, 16-bit

```
void check_drop(char *drop_pathname) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(drop_pathname, "rb");
    int count = 0, pathname_length = 0, c;
    uint8_t drop_hash = 0, current_hash = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        drop_hash = droplet_hash(current_hash, c);
        printf("\ndroplet_hash(0x%02x, 0x%02x) = 0x%02x", current_hash, c, drop_hash);
        current_hash = drop_hash;

        if (count == 12) {
            unsigned int small_hex_val = 0;
            small_hex_val |= (c & 0xFF); // Add the lower byte
            small_hex_val |= ((fgetc(fp) & 0xFF) << 8); // Add the higher byte, taking into account little-endianness
            pathname_length = (int)small_hex_val; // Convert to decimal
        }
        count++;    
    }
    fclose(fp); 
}
```

Ok, this is a function that checks a file that is filled with hexadecimal values. It's supposed to go through the file that I input in and scan the file in a specific pattern until it reaches the hash of the file and restart the scan. Whenever the 12th byte is reached, there is a 2 byte unsigned, 16-bit, little-endian value, which in this case is 01 00. I am able to extract that value in that if statement above and convert that to an integer value of 1 which is correct. But when I do that through shifting the bytes, it messes up the hexadecimal values in the file fp.Is there anyway that I can extract the pathname_length without affected the bytes in file fp? I tried shifting the bytes but I am not exactly sure how to revert the shifts I have done. The printf statement provides this output:

```
droplet_hash(0x00, 0x63) = 0x63
droplet_hash(0x63, 0x38) = 0xfb
droplet_hash(0xfb, 0x2d) = 0x76
droplet_hash(0x76, 0x72) = 0x44
droplet_hash(0x44, 0x77) = 0xb3
droplet_hash(0xb3, 0x2d) = 0x3e
droplet_hash(0x3e, 0x72) = 0x8c
droplet_hash(0x8c, 0x2d) = 0x21
droplet_hash(0x21, 0x2d) = 0x6c
droplet_hash(0x6c, 0x72) = 0x9e
droplet_hash(0x9e, 0x2d) = 0x73
droplet_hash(0x73, 0x2d) = 0xfe
droplet_hash(0xfe, 0x01) = 0xbf -- after this line it messes up. 
droplet_hash(0xbf, 0x61) = 0xfe
droplet_hash(0xfe, 0x01) = 0xbf
droplet_hash(0xbf, 0x00) = 0x9f
droplet_hash(0x9f, 0x00) = 0x7f
droplet_hash(0x7f, 0x00) = 0x5f
droplet_hash(0x5f, 0x00) = 0x3f
droplet_hash(0x3f, 0x00) = 0x1f
droplet_hash(0x1f, 0x0a) = 0xf5
droplet_hash(0xf5, 0x15) = 0x80

This is the correct output:
droplet_hash(0x00, 0x63) = 0x63
droplet_hash(0x63, 0x38) = 0xfb
droplet_hash(0xfb, 0x2d) = 0x76
droplet_hash(0x76, 0x72) = 0x44
droplet_hash(0x44, 0x77) = 0xb3
droplet_hash(0xb3, 0x2d) = 0x3e
droplet_hash(0x3e, 0x72) = 0x8c
droplet_hash(0x8c, 0x2d) = 0x21
droplet_hash(0x21, 0x2d) = 0x6c
droplet_hash(0x6c, 0x72) = 0x9e
droplet_hash(0x9e, 0x2d) = 0x73
droplet_hash(0x73, 0x2d) = 0xfe
droplet_hash(0xfe, 0x01) = 0xbf
droplet_hash(0xbf, 0x00) = 0x9f
droplet_hash(0x9f, 0x61) = 0x1e
droplet_hash(0x1e, 0x01) = 0xdf
droplet_hash(0xdf, 0x00) = 0xbf
droplet_hash(0xbf, 0x00) = 0x9f
droplet_hash(0x9f, 0x00) = 0x7f
droplet_hash(0x7f, 0x00) = 0x5f
droplet_hash(0x5f, 0x00) = 0x3f
droplet_hash(0x3f, 0x0a) = 0x15
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you supplied a [mre].  Either supply input file (you can use xxd to get a hex dump) or use `memfd_create()` to create a file handle with the data.  There is not 12 lines before hitting the `if` statement; body of your if statement has a `getc()` but you don't increment count which looks suspicious.

Comment: What do you mean by "messes up the hexadecimal values in the file"? You can use `ungetc()` to put the extra byte that you read back into the stream, so the next iteration will read it.

Comment: I think when you get to byte 12 you should read the length instead of processing it as a hash. You're treating it as a hash and also as the length.

Comment: Note that [`while (EOF)` is most often wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1270789).

Comment: @SupportUkraine somehow when i remove the code inside of the if(statement) i get the correct output. But i need that code because I want to extract the final byte of the file

Comment: @Barmar I really want to find another way of reading the 12th and 13th hexadecimal value which is a little-endian number normally 0 n 0 0 (n ranges from (0-9)) and converting it into decimal. But without reversing the bytes I don't really know how to.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, Sorry i jst noticed i copied the older output. This is the output as of now.

Comment: @SupportUkraine my bad poor formatting ;(

Comment: Just use the character that you've already read when the count is 12 or 13. `if (count == 12) {pathname_length = c & 0xff;}
else if (count == 13) {pathname_length += (c & 0xff) << 8;}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The output will differ when you run the code with and without the `if` block. It's **not** due to any of the bit shifting. It's because you read a character using `fgetc` inside the `if` block and consequently never calls `droplet_hash` with that character.

There are many ways to solve that. You can put a call of the function (and a print out) inside the `if` block. Or you can put that character back using `ungetc`. Or you can calculate `pathname_length` using two `if` blocks.

Another problem with your current code is that you don't check for EOF inside the `if` block. By using two `if` statements, you can solve that.

Something like the pseudo code below:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    .. call function and print ...

    if (count == 12) {
        ... use current c to calculate first part of pathname_length ...
    } else if (count == 13) {
        ... use current c to calculate final pathname_length ...
    }

    count++;    
}
```

Comment: Tysm guys, I used fseek() function and solve it. Thanks for clarifying